# SSIS script task only throws error at runtime?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have a script task in SSIS package, in which the code is quite strightforward:

```
const int BASE_OVERTIME_MIN = 20;
const int ADDITION_OVERTIME_MIN = 2;
const int MAX_OVERTIME_MIN = 60;

DataTable result = (DataTable)Dts.Variables["ReportList"].Value;
int reportCount = result.Rows.Count;

Dts.Variables["MaxRunTime"].Value = Math.Min(BASE_OVERTIME_MIN + reportCount * ADDITION_OVERTIME_MIN, MAX_OVERTIME_MIN);

Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

The code throws out error without providing any useful info at runtime in SSDT (something like `Exception was thrown by target invocation`).

However, below debug work all failed, which makes the package runs through such code without error:

1.using

```
try{
    //above code
} catch (exception ex){
    //Write them into some log
    throw;
}
```

No Log is found after running and the whole package succeeded.

2. putting a breakpoint inside anywhere to make it go into debug mode
3. its actual run at production server which is using `dtexec.exe`

Finally, I identified that the problem occurs at `Dts.Variables["MaxRunTime"].Value` being set to `int32`, so a force convert into int is required; Nevertheless, I just want to wonder what's the magic behind my debug process, so that such type conversion error will only occur if we are not trying to handle it?

Comment: What is the data type of @[User::MaxRunTime]?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the exception you were encountering.

### Setup

I created a simple SSIS package with 3 Script Tasks and 3 variables.

- User::MaxRunTime Int32 0
- User::ReportList Object
- User::ReportListLength Int32 (first run:10, second run: 70)

### SCR Load ReportList

This script task will populate a trivial DataTable and stuff it into our ReportList variable. The task takes a read only variable of User::ReportListLength and a Read-Write variable of User::ReportList

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ST_LoadVars
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        public void Main()
        {
            int rowCount = System.Int32.Parse(Dts.Variables["User::ReportListLength"].Value.ToString());
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col1", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32")));
            for (int i = 0; i < rowCount ; i++)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { i });
            }

            Dts.Variables["User::ReportList"].Value = dt;
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }

        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
    }
}
```

### SCR Do Calcs

This script task will do the calcs you report and populate the MaxRunTime variable. The task takes a read only variable of User::ReportList and a Read-Write variable of User::MaxRunTime

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ST_DoCalcs
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        public void Main()
        {
            const int BASE_OVERTIME_MIN = 20;
            const int ADDITION_OVERTIME_MIN = 2;
            const int MAX_OVERTIME_MIN = 60;

            DataTable result = (DataTable)Dts.Variables["ReportList"].Value;
            int reportCount = result.Rows.Count;
            int refMaxRunTime = Math.Min(BASE_OVERTIME_MIN + reportCount * ADDITION_OVERTIME_MIN, MAX_OVERTIME_MIN);

            Dts.Variables["MaxRunTime"].Value = refMaxRunTime;

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }

        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
    }
}
```

### SCR Echo Back

This is my most useful debugging script. Your code comment mentions you write into some log. I'm going to "write" into the SSIS run log by raising an Information Event which by default will be in the Output window, the Execution Results tab and in the SSISDB.catalog.operations table.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ST_echoBack
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        public void Main()
        {
            bool fireAgain = false;
            foreach (var item in Dts.Variables)
            {
                Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "SCR Echo Back", string.Format("{0}->{1}", item.QualifiedName, item.Value), "", 0, ref fireAgain);
            }

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }

        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
    }
}
```

### Results

10 rows in our data table yields

[image]

70 rows in our data table yields

[image]